# Add an additional score value to chart, along x-axis?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

It's been a couple of years since I've done reporting.  I have an existing chart with some data/columns, and i want to overlay two other lines along the chart to show a score, and a guess.  Here is a picture of what i want, need to add the blue and red lines.  This might be really simple in SSRS and VS2008, but I am just getting back into it, and not finding anything in the forums.

I have the data there in the queries, so i just need to know how to put it on the chart/axis/whatever.

[image: Chart]

Comment: Would think you could just edit out all the data/numbers, but then again, I don't make the rules at your company :). I'll admit it is slightly difficult to guess with 100% certainty as to what you want.

Comment: I want to add this data point in addition to what's there. The image is here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/95dc0a33-b169-42c8-ba4b-639940a38dde/#95dc0a33-b169-42c8-ba4b-639940a38dde

Comment: I guess it might be something like this, but am having trouble nailing it down.  Part of my problem was that the format of the page was so tight, i couldn't see the data/series/category areas for dropping in data.   http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/chintak/archive/2010/12/02/add-an-average-trend-line-to-column-bar-chart-in-ssrs.aspx

Comment: I guess i can see how this might be confusing. The y-axis is a percentage of people who scored each answer for 1-6. x-axis of 1-6 are the possible scores. There are two other ancillary average scores for the 1-6 scores, like 6.4, 5.7, etc, and i would like to drop them onto the scale if possible